# Windows pngquant failed to build in a gatsby project

Tags: gatsby

I have a gatsby react project that I have been adding packages to the default template. But one ore more of those packages seems to be incompatible with gatsby. I remove the node_modules and yarn.lock file and invoking `yarn install` yields

```
error C:\Users\RKevi\source\repos\gatsby-garb\node_modules\pngquant-bin: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/install.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\RKevi\source\repos\gatsby-garb\node_modules\pngquant-bin
Output:
‼ Response code 500 (Internal Server Error)
  ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
  i compiling from source
  × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at C:\Users\RKevi\source\repos\gatsby-garb\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
```

I know it is related to the packages I install because if I create a fresh gatsby project with `gatsby new  MyNewGatsbyProject` and copy the package.json from the project that is failing the new project also fails to execute yarn install without error. Has anyone had experience with this error building pngquant in a gatsby project?

Comment: I am facing same issue.
I tried installing windows-build-tools on power shell but got stuck same error:

Comment: Output:
‼ getaddrinfo ENOENT raw.githubusercontent.com
  ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
  i compiling from source
  × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Comment: Same situation here. Not sure if that is only on Windows, I see people with other OS have similar issues.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be an issue with Github being down. The error is a 500, the exact same you get when visiting Github.

See: https://www.githubstatus.com/

> **Investigating** - We are investigating reports of degraded performance and increased error rates.”.
>
> Jul 13, 04:06 UTC